# How can I check whether an ISA extension is supported by current ARM CPU?

Tags: arm, instruction-set, cpuid, platform-detection

When a userspace program on x86 needs to determine whether e.g. AVX extension is supported, it can use CPUID instruction. Is there any similarly OS-independent way to check support for an ISA extension (e.g. NEON) in ARM?

Comment: the arm has an array of CPUID registers which include quite a few is this instruction there is that instruction there, or you can just go off the main ID register to some extent.  its right there in the arm docs

Comment: @old_timer but [CPUD register](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0497a/CIHCAGHH.html) seems to be system-access only. Similarly for the [c0, CPUID registers](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0301h/Babgbeed.html), `Processor Feature Register 0 is: <...> * accessible in privileged modes only.`. So this doesn't help the userspace program which the question is about.

Comment: the tags and the question are about arm instruction set and os independent so that is the correct answer, if this was a linux or windows question (and user vs system level access) and had those tags then there would be a different answer.

Comment: @old_timer, the question does state that this is required in *a userspace program*.  It may be that the answer is, "the necessary instructions are not available in non-privileged modes; you'll need OS support."

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cpuinfo](https://github.com/pytorch/cpuinfo) which is a cross-platform CPU information library

> Check if the host CPU supports ARM NEON
>
> ```c
> cpuinfo_initialize();
> if (cpuinfo_has_arm_neon()) {
>     neon_implementation(arguments);
> }
> ```
>
> Check if the thread runs on a Cortex-A53 core
>
> ```c
> cpuinfo_initialize();
> switch (cpuinfo_get_current_core()->uarch) {
>     case cpuinfo_uarch_cortex_a53:
>         cortex_a53_implementation(arguments);
>         break;
>     default:
>         generic_implementation(arguments);
>         break;
> }
> ```
>
> Get the size of level 1 data cache on the fastest core in the processor (e.g. big core in big.LITTLE ARM systems):
>
> ```c
> cpuinfo_initialize();
> const size_t l1_size = cpuinfo_get_processor(0)->cache.l1d->size;
> ```
>
> Pin thread to cores sharing L2 cache with the current core (Linux or Android)
>
> ```c
> cpuinfo_initialize();
> cpu_set_t cpu_set;
> CPU_ZERO(&cpu_set);
> const struct cpuinfo_cache* current_l2 = cpuinfo_get_current_processor()->cache.l2;
> for (uint32_t i = 0; i < current_l2->processor_count; i++) {
>     CPU_SET(cpuinfo_get_processor(current_l2->processor_start + i)->linux_id, &cpu_set);
> }
> pthread_setaffinity_np(pthread_self(), sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpu_set);
> ```

Comment: Cross-platform doesn't mean OS-independent. In particular, this library doesn't seem to support FreeRTOS or even bare-metal environments, from what I found in its README.

Comment: of course if you want to support multiple OSes then you have to write platform-specific code because the OS typically won't allow direct hardware access, the library is only an abstraction layer. If no one added support for that platform then unfortunately you need to do that yourself