# Detect ARM instruction-set version?

Tags: assembly, arm, instruction-set, armv8

I am writing a piece of code which depending on the different versions of instruction set implemented by various vendor might behave differently.
These are the different versions of ARMv8 instruction set, like ARM v8.1, v8.2, v8.6.

Is there any register which can tell at runtime the version of ARM instruction(ARMv8) set that is implemented on an ARM cpu?

Comment: Related: [How can I check whether an ISA extension is supported by current ARM CPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45466855) - yes there is a register, apparently, which can be read by kernel code only.

Comment: You could try looking at the OpenSSL source for some ideas. I believe they have a couple of different methods for this, one of which is to simply attempting to execute a given instruction and checking if it triggers a SIGILL.

Comment: the cpuid registers are there to tell you all of this.  there is only one (full sized aarch64) armv8 at the moment and the aarch32 on those cores is armv7-a

Comment: Is this bare metal, or under some OS?  Since the relevant registers are privileged (EL1 and higher), when running at EL0 you're expected to get the information from the OS in some fashion.

Comment: This is EL1 level code running on top of an hypervisor at EL2.

Comment: @PeterCordes The link that you added has answer as CPUID register. ARMv8-A architecture doesn't have that register anymore. The other register that it talks about in MIDR_EL1 register which when I read on Apple - M1 is all 0s.

Comment: There's a list of ID registers at K14.3.3 of the Architecture Reference Manual.  I think for instance that `ID_AA64ISAR0_EL1` and `ID_AA64ISAR1_EL1` tell you about available instructions.  Still though I don't think `MIDR_EL1` ought to read as zero under any circumstances, so if you are getting zero there could be something wrong with your code, or else the hypervisor is trapping your attempt to access it and not bothering to emulate a reasonable value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, there isn't register which would directly provide the Arm Instruction set version implemented. Secondly, you can query the features implemented using registers that start with ID_*.
For example, ID_AA64ISAR0_EL1 has AES field which tells if AES=1/2 then AES instructions are implemented, ID_AA64PFR0_EL1.FP tells if floating point arithmetic implemented or not.

To say if implementation is compliant to or implements say Arm V8.2, then there are set of mandatory features that needs to be implemented. This is described under chapter A2 of Arm reference manual. For example, if you want to know if V8.6 is present then Fine Grain Trap and Enhanced Counter Virtualization are mandatory features to be implemented. ID_AA64MMFR0_EL1.{FGT, ECV } fields would tell the presence of these features and if present then you can say Arm V8.6 instruction set is implemented

MIDR_EL1 register has field "Architecture" which would probably be set to 0x1111 indicating the features implemented can be known using ID_* registers. Other fields in this register are IMPLEMENTATION_DEFINED value and could be set to zero. Probably Apple might have chosen to set the "Architecuture" field to zero and hence you are seeing value of MIDR_EL1 as zero.

Comment: Referring the Arm's ARM Jan 2021 revision, it seems both Implementer & Architecture bits shouldn't be zero as they are Reserved values.

Comment: Furthermore, I am not interested in whether the a particular feature is available or not, instead the version of ARM v8 instruction set that is implemented.
This is required to find out whether a particular register, such as ID_DFR1_EL1, exist or not.
If I am correct, presence of ID_DFR1_EL1 is not influenced by any of the FEAT_*.

Comment: There isn't any register which would provide the version of Arm V8 instruction set. To say if implementation is compliant to or implements Arm V8.2, then there are set of mandatory features that needs to be implemented. This is described under chapter A2 of Arm Arm reference manual.  ID_DFR1_EL1 is an ID register and doesn't depend on any feature to be implemented. Its the register which tells if certain features are implemented or not. Take example, GCR_EL1, this register is implemented only when MTE feature is implemented and this is indicated by ID_AA64PFR1.MTE field.

Comment: Regarding MIDR_EL1, though reference manual says zero is reserved, there can be exceptions.

Comment: Regarding ID_DFR1_EL1, the spec says that it is available since v8.6, refer Table D12-2.
IMO, reading such a register before v8.6 version of instruction set will result in undefined behaviour. This undefined behaviour is what I want to avoid by verifying which version of instruction set is available on the chip.

Comment: As told before there isn't a way to know the version of instruction set. As mentioned under chapter A2 or ARM ARM, you have to query for mandatory features to know the instruction set. If you want to know if V8.6 is present then Fine Grain Trap and Enhanced Counter Virtualization are mandatory features to be implemented. ID_AA64MMFR0_EL1.{FGT, ECV } fields would tell the presence of these features and if present then you can say V8.6 is implemented.

Comment: @TheExcitedEngineer, kindly upvote or accept answer if it has has helped to solve your problem. Thanks.